# Which API should I use for extracting info from an image?

Tags: java, image, image-recognition, information-extraction

I am trying to extract informations from images but since I never did anything like that I don't know which API I should use.

All images are like this one below:

[Example Image](https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/products/2018/12/01/pokemon_go_high_cp_pokmon_1543597194_d21ecbca.jpg)

First off, I would an API that would let me programatically cut the image like this:

[Cut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkqCN.png)

As you can see, I removed some of the upper and lower (the last line of Pokèmon that were partially covered) part of the image.

After this, I should begin with the extracting process. What I need to extract are the Pokèmon info (Name, CP and possibly the icon).

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to extract the info from the image is the [Text Recognition API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview). This API lets you extract textual information from a picture. Implementing this correctly could also make cropping the image obsolete.

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/teachmind/detect-text-from-image-in-android-with-google-mobile-vision-api-112a527e556d) should get you started. If implementing it similar to the tutorial, you should be able to get all the info in your screenshot in a textual form.

You can then extract the infos you need and throw away the rest. e.g. get a collection of all the existing pokemon and look for an occurence in the screenshot.